# Does prebid version 1.X have a way to check for status of bids?

Tags: prebid.js

I am trying to upgrade prebid v0.34.10 to v1.11.0 and I noticed *getBidResponses()* behaves differently between the two versions.

For v0.34.10, if nobody participates in the auction, then in the `statusMessage` it would say `Bid returned empty or error response`

For v1.11.0, if nobody participates in the auction, then the same method will just return with a smaller list of adUnits with a smaller list of bidders.

I took a look at the [upgrade notes](http://prebid.org/dev-docs/prebid-1.0-API.html) but I didn't see any mentions for the problem above.

Does anyone know if there is a config or alternative method I can use to check the status of an bid? I was using the *getBidResponses()* method to create e2e tests for our implementation

Answer (score 0):

Prebid version 1+ doesn't record bids coming after the timeout while v0.34 does.

For more info check out this issue:
https://github.com/prebid/Prebid.js/issues/2640